# What is the correct behavior for Angular service observables when an object is not found?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I ran into an architectural question regarding the use of `rxjs` and observables when making a call to a data service in Angular.

Suppose I have the following:

```
displayDetails(id: String): void {
  this._dataService.getById(id).subscribe(o => this.currentItem = o);
}
```

What if the item with the given `id` cannot be found? Currently, my service returns an undefined object to the caller, which could lead to an undefined object being set as the current item and then data binding errors being printed to the console in a worst-case scenario.

Is there a commonly-accepted approach for this? Would it be better to return call the `error` function when the item with the given `id` could not be loaded?

Comment: You have to do what works best for you. It is a problem specific to your situation and a best practice used by someone else may not apply. I do understand the problem and frustration in trying to make a decision, but one could argue that a HTTP 404 is an error while another person could argue it's technically a successful HTTP request because it yielded a response. Is an error a protocol error is it is a business logic error? Only you can make this decision.

Comment: @cgTag - respectfully, I disagree. APIs should follow common semantics, not be arbitrary per developer or per project.

Answer (score 0):

No, returning `error` would not be appropriate, because `undefined` is not an `error`. Instead you could handle that within your `subscribe` and show error message or take any action required.

```
displayDetails(id: String): void {
    this._dataService.getById(id).subscribe(o => { 
                if(o) {
                  this.currentItem = o;
                }
                else {
                  //show or log error
                }
      });
  }
```

`Errors` are thrown for ex, if there is a bad request error from your server or any logical errors that occur while dealing with observable data.

Comment: A rest-ful implementation might return a 404 error when making a request for a resource that does not exist. So is this an error? Or a normal response? I guess that's the gist of my question.